# Fragment a TCP package and making them overlap using socket in python3?

Tags: security, networking, python-3.7

I am taking a network security course and we use kali and a metasploitable machine to preform scans and attacks. I found out that the version is vulnerable to the Teardrop attack, so I want to try it out. I could not find a program in Kali that can do it so I though I may just write a program by my own.

However, I can not find a way to change the flag to use fragmentation. Do anyone know how to do this? Is python's socket package too high level and I have to dive into NW coding in C instead?

Comment: Have you tried to search for packet crafting tool / packet builder / packet sender tool?

Comment: Python itself does only offer high-level API for TCP/IP. Hence I would go for libraries that base on pcap (as it allows raw network access) such as for example "Scapy" and it's forks.